# Cannot install Composer on Windowsn 10 Pro build 1809: SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, composer-php

I tried to install Composer on a fresh newly installed Windows 10 Pro build 1809 and I got this error message.

> The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].
>   OpenSSL failed with a 'certificate verify failed' error. This
>   indicates a problem with the Certificate Authority file(s) on your
>   system, which may be out of date.

Certificate location [from openssl.cafile ini setting]:

```
D:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: `D:\xampp\php\php.ini`

Script Output:

```
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
    Failed to enable crypto
    failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I've tried to replace the "curl-ca-bundle.crt" with "cacert.pem" from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert or with "ca-bundle.crt" but it's nothing, the error messages still happened.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this problem. Because my company's blocked something on the network. Then I try to switched to the other network, then It's succuessfully installed!